# "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" in HttpWebRequest, even after specifying ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In order to meet PCI compliance, we have had to completely disable TLS 1.0 from our servers. Ever since doing this, I have had to specify which protocol to use when making web requests in order for things to work. However, one particular problem persists. Even when I specify the protocol, I still get the error stated in the title.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(body);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    return result;
}
```

The error itself is generated from the line -

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

As you can see, I am specifying to use either TLS 1.1 or 1.2 (I originally had it at 1.2 only, but thought allowing 1.1 as well would help, but it did not).

Additionally (not sure if this is pertinent or not), this particular snippet of code is always calling an API that we also run and maintain, so essentially, the server is calling itself to get a piece of info it needs.

And I am fast running out of ideas on what I can try to further debug or fix this, so any help out there would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tell us more about the context - eg using IIS for example?

Comment: Yes, application is running in IIS on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server. Application is using .NET 4.6.2. I'm not sure if any other info is needed, but if so, let me know, and I'm happy to provide any info that helps you help me :)

Comment: i would be checking the setting for IIS especially the Configuration

Comment: Ok, do you know where I specifically need to check in IIS? Sorry to be a pain, but I just don't know where I'd go to check for this sort of thing.

Comment: run inetmgr.exe command

Comment: does the API you are calling to has a valid TLS/SSL certificate? Can you access that URL from the browser on that server where IIS is running?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, once I have the IIS manager open, where do you want me to check in there?

Comment: Yes, the API I am calling has a valid certificate, and is being used thousands of times per day by many other external parties.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this one out, and the solution is far simpler than I'd like to admit. I simply moved the line

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

to the very top of the code snippet I posted in the question, and everything has been working since. I'm guessing it needs to be in place before creating the HttpWebRequest?